# Why can I not see newly inserted JSON documents?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, couchbase

Why can I not see newly inserted JSON documents?????

- Couchbase 4.5
- JavaScript
- AngularJS
- Node.JS
- Express Server

I have a web application, which performances data maintenance.  The user will select from a menu, which data to manipulate.  The user has the option of inserting, updating, or deleting once the web application retrieves the data.  I ran several tests of the application and discovered an issue.

**Background to the Issue:**

Couchbase server resides on Local Computer

Application written using JavaScript, AngularJS, NodeJS running Express Server

User enters new data into the web application.  Once completed, the user will depress an update button, which determines if the user wants to insert or update a JSON document.  The web application determines the user is adding new data to the database.  The web application formats the data into the appropriate JSON document format.  The web application sends the data to the database using the REST paradigm.  The database returns a success status back to the web application.  Upon recognizing the successful database update occurred, the web application retrieves the data in order to display the must current data.

**Issue:**

After reviewing the new retrieval of the data, the record just inserted does not display.  After waiting a few minutes, I re-retrieved the data again.  The newly inserted data appears.  I ran the process several times.  Each time I could not immediately retrieve the newly inserted data.

**Questions:**

Can someone explain to me why a JSON document of less than 1000 characters will not retrieve after insertion?

Will I need to insert the new inserted data into my existing result set?  If so, why when the data resides in the database?

TIA

Comment: Could you show the node.js code that receives the update command from the UI, does the server update and returns the response? Do not forget that all IO code is asynchronous.

Comment: I using standard REST request (POST) to insert the JSON document in the database.

Comment: Anthony, just post related code. You can give all the description of the world, but it can always be incorrect. Code do not lie and everyone will be on the same page. What would be helpful is to post the code that handles the request from the client application and interacts with the database API and returns back a response to the client. If you created abstractions over the native database API then post the related implementation details as well.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about N1QL or views querying, if so, you probably operating on default consistency levels, which trades immediate update for performance. If that is critical at point in your application, you should pick different consistency level.

Overview of the feature: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/architecture/querying-data-with-n1ql.html

Blog post with video demo: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/july/n1ql-scan-consistency-including-new-atplus-video

N1QL API to change consistency: https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/771ebf78f82b437999e13b05e4699c88a02dc8d3/lib/n1qlquery.js#L71

Comment: My insert into the database using the REST command of POST.  There is no N1QL statement performing the insert but I used a N1QL to retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: Which endpoint you are using to insert data? There is no "standard" REST API for Couchbase. Are you sure you are not using CouchDB? It is completely different databases, which have only "couch"  in common.

Comment: I am using the nodejs Couchbase API through a REST POST function call.  Listed below you will find the description, engine and node engine entries from the package JSON                                                   "description": "The official Couchbase Node.js Client Library.",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.8"
  },

Comment: could you tell what API calls in node.js SDK used to "retrieves the data in order to display the must current data" and when you are inserting data into database. Angular has nothing to do with Couchbase, please define your problem in terms of node.js application.

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge, I believe my retrieve of data is using the the 'CouchbaseModel.queryN1ql' from the Couchbase API.

Comment: So if it is area of backend team, they should check docs on N1QL consistency and use it appropriately in cases when web UI is sensitive to the query results

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Since the company does not have a backend team, I guess I will have to figure out how to implement N1QL consistency process.

Comment: In this case, maybe show use how update and fetch implemented on the node.js side? I belive that fetch side is using something like I referenced in my answer. So you will just use something like `N1qlQuery.Consistency.REQUEST_PLUS` or whatever fits you better but keep in mind that the fastest way would be `N1qlQuery.Consistency.NOT_BOUNDED`